# How do I translate form validation in Symfony 3?

Tags: yaml, symfony

Got everything in my form validating using i18n just fine but cant figure out how to translate the form validation. For example right now when I try and submit the form with an empty field I get the pop-up validation message "Please fill out this field."

Translation is turned on and annotations enabled:

```
// config_dev.yml
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
    translator: { fallback: en }
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

Entity is rigged for validation annotations:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
....
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Custom validation error message")
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=512)
     */
    private $url;
```

I also created the file validators.en.yml in my app/Resources/translations folder but not sure where to go from here. Can anyone help?

Comment: You see message from your browser, you even not submitted the form. This is a HTML5 validation message, not related to Symfony.

Comment: @malcolm  The message appears as you submit the form. Next answer....

Comment: If you see the tooltip with message that is the HTML5 validation message. Symfony validation messages appears after form is submitted and page is reloaded/redirected, but you know better... If you want to know, the default message for not_blank assert in Symfony is: "This value should not be blank." and you get "Please fill out this field." the default message from your browser.

Comment: @malcolm Ok yes what I have setup will only help write messages for error messages returned after the form is submitted. I was wrong, admittedly. I need to find out how to translate that HTML5 message that pops up if you try to submit a required field that is empty. Hmmmm

Comment: You can do it in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could translate validation messages in `app/Resources/translations/validators.fr.xlf` (example for french xlf translation file)

Here the Docs you are looking for: http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/translations.html